# Cannot find the IndentationError: unexpected indent error?

Tags: python, indentation

> #Modify the code below so that the function sense, which 
>       #takes p and Z as inputs, will output the NON-normalized 
>       #probability distribution, q, after multiplying the entries 
>       #in p by pHit or pMiss according to the color in the 
>       #corresponding cell in world.

```
p=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
world=['green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green']
Z = 'red'
pHit = 0.6
pMiss = 0.2

    def sense(p, Z):
    q=[]
    for i in range(p):
        if(Z==word[i]):
            q.append(p[i]*pMiss)
        else:
            q.append(p[i]*pHit)
    return q

print sense(p,Z)
```

Comment: pylint is good starter-kit for you
https://www.pylint.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function signature is not properly indented, look at following code :

```
p=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
world=['green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green']
Z = 'red'
pHit = 0.6
pMiss = 0.2

def sense(p, Z):
    q=[]
    for i in range(p):
        if(Z==word[i]):
            q.append(p[i]*pMiss)
        else:
            q.append(p[i]*pHit)
    return q

print sense(p,Z)
```

> **Note:** A code block (body of a function, loop etc.) starts with indentation and ends with the first unindented line. The amount of indentation is up to you, but it must be consistent throughout that block.

Answer (score 1):

`def sense(p, Z):` should not be indented.

Comment: @zmag my response exactly and precisely answers the question where the indentation error is, namely the `def` statement.